# How much energy does a cosmic ray lose before it hits a detector?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, astronomy, cosmic-rays

The origin of extremely high energy cosmic rays is still unclear, by my understanding. But say that they are produced by whatever local source does it: how much energy is lost to environmental effects including CMB, electromagnetic interactions, and interactions with the Earth's atmosphere? When they record a cosmic ray of high energy, how do they record its energy at the location of detection and can they estimate how much it had while it traveled through space?

Comment: FYI: The "location" of detection may actually be a significant parcel of real estate. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_shower_(physics)

Comment: @SolomonSlow yes, there is so much complication in the real scenario I’m not privy to that I was hoping an expert could more or less fill in whatever is needed to make sense of the question.

Comment: @Diffycue better read the article give by solomon. Very high energy cosmic rays interact at the top of the atmosphere and are detected by the shower of particles created which reach a large area on the ground.

Comment: @annav The article is of insufficient generality and specificity. For instance the AMS experiment operates in the international space station and its data contributes a large part to state-of-the-art understanding of these rays. And in the showers how can one tell what fraction of energy is carried off by neutrons whose detection is difficult? I do not presume to know all the complications which is why I ask people not Google. If a real expert actually answers my question maybe the article can be improved.

Comment: There are other issues such as how one tells that the shower detected by scintillators was "the" shower and not one of many showers produced by spallation products of an even higher-energy ray.

Comment: Probably depends on circumstances. For instance, cosmic ray protons can collide with ambient protons and generate $\gamma$'s (from decaying $\pi_0$ or $\pi_\pm$), the energy of the $\gamma$ there represents the energy lost by the CR proton. You can also get [CR spallation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_ray_spallation) effects, which will reduce the energy as well (also depends on impact energies).

Comment: And CRs themselves are usually charged, so they can be deflected by magnetic fields in space (hence their disassociation of direction and source), which can gain or lose energy, depending on scenarios. I imagine most modelers just assume that $E_\text{measured}$ is basically identical to $E_\text{escape}$, but I've not looked into this in ~7 years.

Comment: @KyleKanos Thanks for the info! I have done some reading since I posted this question and there is a lot of phenomenology. I might compose an answer soon.